# How to omit heading in df -k command of SunOs

Tags: linux, command-line, sunos

Input: `df -k`

Output:

```
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0    10332220  443748 9785150     5%    /
/devices                   0       0       0     0%    /devices
ctfs                       0       0       0     0%    /system/contract
proc                       0       0       0     0%    /proc
mnttab                     0       0       0     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                 45475864    1688 45474176     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                      0       0       0     0%    /system/object
sharefs                    0       0       0     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3    10332220 3513927 6714971    35%    /usr
```

I want to omit the 1st line `Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on` from the output.

I used `df -k | tail -n+2` in linux to get exactly what i wanted, but in SunOs I get

```
zenvo% df -k | tail -n+2
usage: tail [+/-[n][lbc][f]] [file]
   tail [+/-[n][l][r|f]] [file]
```

How can i achieve the **Required output**:

```
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s0    10332220  443748 9785150     5%    /
/devices                   0       0       0     0%    /devices
ctfs                       0       0       0     0%    /system/contract
proc                       0       0       0     0%    /proc
mnttab                     0       0       0     0%    /etc/mnttab
swap                 45475864    1688 45474176     1%    /etc/svc/volatile
objfs                      0       0       0     0%    /system/object
sharefs                    0       0       0     0%    /etc/dfs/sharetab
/dev/dsk/c0t0d0s3    10332220 3513927 6714971    35%    /usr
```

**Note**: No. of rows might change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used SunOS but using sed you should be able to delete the first line like this:

```
df -k | sed -e /Filesystem/d
```

edit: But you would have to be careful that the word Filesystem doesn't show up elsewhere in the output.  A better solution would be:

```
df -k | sed -e /^Filesystem/d
```

Comment: This would fail to work properly if some joker mounted FS to a location like `/somewhere/Filesystem/hehe/`. Just saying.

Comment: This does not work properly on languages other than English. (Admittedly rare situation especially on servers, but still to be considered.)

Answer (score 47):

I know it's an old thread, but the shortest and the clearest of all:

```
df -k | sed 1d
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to omit the first line of any result, you can use tail:

```
<command> | tail -n +2
```

So in your case:

```
df -k | tail -n +2
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
df -k | tail -$((`df -k | wc -l`-1))
```

Comment: shows some error, here is the output ` df -k | tail -$((`df -k | wc -l`-1))
Variable syntax` @wollw: solved my problem